# AWS: What is the difference between Burst Balance and EBS IO Balance metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

AWS Docs describe Burst Balance and EEBS IO Balance in the following way:

> BurstBalance The percent of General Purpose SSD (gp2) burst-bucket I/O
> credits available.
>
> EBSIOBalance% The percentage of I/O credits remaining in the burst
> bucket of your RDS database. This metric is available for basic
> monitoring only. **This metric is different from BurstBalance**

However, as far as I know, the docs do not explain how those two metrics are different.

Comment: One is an absolute value, one is a percentage.

Comment: @Tim They are both percentages as quoted above "BurstBalance The **percent** of General Purpose SSD (gp2) burst-bucket I/O credits available" "EBSIOBalance% The **percentage** of I/O credits remaining in the burst bucket of your RDS database". Indeed we have been recently running out of EBSIOBalance but not of BurstBalance.

Comment: (Not to be confused with `EBSByteBalance%`.)

Answer (score 3):

BurstBalance is an [EC2 / EBS metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using_cloudwatch_ebs.html) (EBS falls under the EC2 namespace). EBSIOBalance% is an [RDS metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html). Under RDS you can't see the EBS volume burst balance directly which is why RDS has to expose it.

Comment: And yet I have burst balance in RDS with gp2 storage. It goes away with gp3 storage, however.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions "Under RDS you can't see the EBS volume burst balance directly which is why RDS has to expose it". i.e. RDS shows you the storage burst balance.